# Where can I find a Strength Chart for Wood and Steel by size and length?

Tags: concrete

I am looking for charts for the Strength of 2x boards by span distance and the same for Angle Iron steel.
Like 4x4 x 1/4 thick in 2 feet lengths or 2x4, 2x6, 2x8, 2x10, 2x12 and lengths like 6-8-10-12-14-16 feet.  How much they can support.

Comment: Why in the world is this tagged [tag:concrete]? Also, have you tried searching for "dimensional lumber span chart"? I'm 99.99% certain that will get you what you're looking for.

Comment: Define your load and then there are many sites and even local building offices or inspectors with the equations available to calculate the size needed.

Comment: https://awc.org/codes-standards/calculators-software/spancalc

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you’ll ever find a table that compares wood joists (2x sizes) with steel angles based on distance (span). Wood framing tables are measured in pounds (ponds per foot, total pounds, etc.) and steel is measured in kips (pounds to the one thousand).